# Getting array from php exec() when result is array

Tags: php, arrays, exec, gcloud

I have the following code:

```
$transcribe1 = exec('"C:\path\to\gcloud\gcloud.cmd" ml speech recognize "audio-file.flac" --language-code="en-GB"', $transcribe2);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($transcribe1); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($transcribe2); echo '</pre>';
$transcribeArray = json_decode($transcribe1, true);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($transcribeArray); echo '</pre>';
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {
    [1] =>   "results": [
    [2] =>     {
    [3] =>       "alternatives": [
    [4] =>         {
    [5] =>           "confidence": 0.880379,
    [6] =>           "transcript": "the text returned from google cloud"
    [7] =>         }
    [8] =>       ]
    [9] =>     }
    [10] =>   ]
    [11] => }
)
```

The first two `print_r`s return empty.

All I'm trying to do is get the json returned from gCloud into an array so I can reference it properly in the rest of the code. In other words, an array that looks like this:

```
[results] => Array(
  [alternatives] => Array(
    [confidence] => "0.880379",
    [transcript] => "the text returned from google cloud"
  );
);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out with more StackOverflow searching.

`exec` returns a whole array of stuff it does

`shell_exec` returns only the result of the execution, in its original format.